# change jquery mobile listview background color

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile-listview

I am a beginner when it comes to coding and I need some help. I am designing an app using Dreamweaver CS6 and using the Jquery Mobile template. All I want to do is change my listview buttons so that the background of them is red. I have tried going to themeroller, downloading my new theme, unzipping it and inserting it into my site. But it will not override the original themes at all. I copied the code they provided, placed it in my header; I've tried placing it above the existing stylesheets, as well as below, and still no override. I also changed the href to actually go to where the files are:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/style1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/jquery-mobile-theme-073626-0/themes/redtheme.css" />`

I am wondering if there's a way I could just edit the original jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css file so that the listview buttons on theme "a" are red, not black. I've been searching through the code and trying different things with no success. Please help, I really feel like this shouldn't be so difficult, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the links like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href"includes/jquery-mobile-theme-073626-0/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/style1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/jquery-mobile-theme-073626-0/themes/redtheme.css" />
```

In CSS, the styles( and stylesheets) further down in the page override other CSS, unless the selectors are more specific.
For example, if there was the selector `.mobile` in the jQuery css file, and also in the redtheme file, the red theme file will override, since it is further down the page.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. And I just realized, I inserted the wrong 2 lines above. I have style1.css that has custom css in it that overrides some stuff just fine (such as a background image). redtheme.css is what I'm trying to get to work. Sorry about that. Here is all of my header objects to clarify:

Comment: '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/style1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/jquery-mobile-theme-073626-0/themes/redtheme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href"includes/jquery-mobile-theme-073626-0/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'

Comment: Ok, I changed things around like you said, and my list is still black instead of red :/. When I have the jQuery Mobile Swatches window up, it still shows the original swatches, not my custom ones.